# How to read_csv file from url with pandas on proxy?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, proxy, dataset, data-science

I'm getting problems reading csv files using pandas on proxy in my student dorm:

```
drinks=pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/drinks.csv')
type(drinks)
```

I've try this, but it didn't help me:

```
import pandas as pd
import io
import requests

proxy_dict = "http://proxy.rcub.bg.ac.rs:8080"

s = requests.get('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/pandas-videos/master/data/drinks.csv', proxies=proxy_dict).text

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s))
```

but I get these errors:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/itgiO.jpg)

Any help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `proxy_dict` is a string, not a dict. Use

```
proxy_dict = {"https": "http://proxy.rcub.bg.ac.rs:8080"}
```

Comment: Thx a lot! Usually we don't see the smallest mistakes hehe. Now, it works!